# Developing a loader CSS element in an Ember/Rails app. It will display properly in a codepen/jsfiddle but not in the actual app.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ember.js

I am developing a generic loader for our app that uses the built in ember loading substate. It currently uses a bit ID'd loading to pull it, then pulls this loading piece from the controller (Details here: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/). It is properly pulling up this loading state, and displaying text/other animations I have done so I know it to not be a problem with my assets or it loading the specific CSS being used. This is the snippet for the animation:

```
$bg: #f0efee; $c: #c31230; $size: 60px; $ease: 1s ease-out;
body { background: $bg; }
#loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 0; height: 0; margin: auto;
  @include border-radius(100%);
  @include box-shadow(inset 0 0 0 $size/2 $c);
  animation: load $ease infinite;
}
@keyframes load {
  100% { width: $size; height: $size; box-shadow: none; }
}
```

And here it is being called in the main application view in the loading template (as an emblem file):

```
#loading
```

And here is a codepen of this working live: http://cdpn.io/CczlK

I have tried breaking it in just about every way imagineable, but all other loaders I have tried that are pure CSS3 have functioned properly and I have no idea where to go from here. Anyone have some suggestions or another way to break it that might help me dig a little further in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing vendor prefixes on animation. Compass unfortunately doesn't include those. You'll need to either use Bourbon instead of Compass (my recommendation) or add separate properties for:

```
-webkit-animation
-moz-animation
-ms-animation
-o-animation
animation
```

And also each for @keyframes (so `@-webkit-keyframes` and so on). It appears that it was working on CodePen because they must be adding the prefixes for you.